# Alterar o css de um elemento pelo id

Tags: javascript, jquery

eu tentei o seguinte codigo:

```
$("#maintenanceRequest").css({"backgroundColor": "black"});
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:26
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Obrigada

Comment: Bruna, o problema pode estar em outra parte do código. A forma de alterar o CSS do elemento está correta e deveria funcionar.

Comment: O jQuery esta na pagina?, Ele esta disponível no momento em que você executa esse código?,  Faço essas perguntas porque mesmo que jQuery não tivesse encontrado o *selector* a função `.css` ainda estaria disponível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que estou vendo, você está tentando implementar o css em um jquery, o que não é necessário e aconselho a utilizar uma folha de estilo separada do projeto para melhor organização do seu código.

## Possíveis soluções:

Se aderir a utilizar uma folha de estilo, seria assim:

```
#maintenanceRequest{
   background-color: black;
}
```

ou se quiser estilizar somente no conteúdo (uma `<div>` por exemplo) basta utilizar a tag `<style>` que ficaria assim EX.:

```
<div style="background-color: black;"></div>
```

> OBS: seja mais específica quando for detalhar sua dúvida/problema pois como você postou fica difícil de identificar onde exatamente é o problema, sugiro editar sua pergunta, eu respondi pois o problema é simples e não precisava ser algo tão específico.

espero poder ter ajudado de alguma forma :)

Comment: O problema é se o propósito for alterar o CSS de forma dinâmica, o que é muito comum.

Comment: verdade por isso pedi para que ela editasse a pergunta, e dissesse de forma clara, o que realmente quer fazer